# Estimate the absolute error

Tags: numerical-methods

Assume that we know the approximate value a* of the real number a, and the approximate value b* of the real number b, i.e. a≈a* and b≈b*.
Assuming that a, b ∈ [−2, 4], estimate the absolute error abserr(a · b, a* · b*).

Can someone help me with this question?

There is a hint that I can use |ab - a* b*| = |ab - ab* + ab* - a* b*| and that x* 10^-k < x < x* + 10^-k

Comment: You mean $|ab - a b^* + ab^* - a^* b^*|$.

Comment: Right my mistake

Comment: Further hint: by triangle inequality this $\le |a b - a b^*| + |ab^* - a^* b^*|$.

Comment: This is an obvious thing not a hint.

Comment: The whole thing is not much less obvious.